# Repeatedly ill after going to Mikvah

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, choleh-sick

A number of times after my wife has been to the Mikvah (but not every time) she is ill on that night with symptoms very much like a stomach bug and each time has been up for hours in the night in a lot of pain and being sick several times.  After a few hours, she is able to go to sleep and feels a lot better by morning.  She often does seem to complain of discomfort before she goes, but it has happened about 5 or 6 times on the night she has gone and it seems very improbable that it could be a coincidence.  Has anyone else experienced/heard of this kind of problem and/or does anyone know what might be the cause of it?

Comment: you need to think about neurovegetative symptoms of anxiety

Comment: @kouty we have discussed whether it could be anxiety and she does get a bit anxious about it beforehand, but we both find it difficult to believe that it is (just) that as she doesn't seem to suffer these symptoms when she seems to be far more anxious about other things which she seems far more anxious about.

Comment: Sounds like something which you should try talking to the Rabbi of the community about. He can look into the mikva status as far as health is concerned, and can speak to the mikva attendant to figure out if there appears to be clues of a physical or emotional question going on here.

Comment: It sounds like women can give you a better answer to this than men. I have heard, unfortunately, of "unsanitary" mikva'ot. I've also, sadly, seen a few, myself (not while people were there, of course.) That MIGHT be the problem. You should inquire how often the mikvah is cleaned and who is inspecting the cleanliness. More easily, you or your wife might glean some info from other community women. There shouldn't be any complaints from anyone about cleanliness. If there are even one or two, I think it's something to carefully consider.

Comment: In addition to the mikvah, I gather that the attendants sometimes use a nail file or some other "tools:" as part of their inspection (e.g. to clean under nails, etc.) How clean are those things? Perhaps the shower or tub has a problem. Perhaps the floors are accumulating bacteria, mold, etc. These are all possible factors. The rooms, really should be scrubbed or some mild disinfectant, etc. should be placed after each person leaves the room. It takes a minute or 2 to do this.

Comment: Try a different Mikvah?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a "Judaism" question. It may have something to do with the mikvah, it may not. Prior to going to both the mikvah and your rav, she should probably see a doctor. Have her mention the timing of her symptoms. He might correlate it to something (bacteria, etc.) in the mikvah, or not. Checking the cleanliness of the mikvah is a separate issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  I think for the moment, next time she is going to try a different Mikvah, although that will only tell us something if it does happen then (it doesn't most times).  I agree that I'm not sure whether this was a Judaism question as such, I was just hoping that someone may have posted that they had a similar experience and couldn't think where else to ask the question.  I think that since it happens relatively infrequently, she seems to recover pretty quickly and her doctor isn't Jewish, we're not going to go that route right now.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it is the Mikvah - pretty sure it is the largest and busiest one in town and seems to have continual refurbishment work going on there and my wife thought she could smell chlorine in the water so I think they do take at least some measures to ensure hygiene.  I think it falls under the auspices of our local Beth Din, not an individual Rabbi, and there are a number of different attendants so don't think that would help (I think there are about 15 rooms there).  I could contact the Beth Din and see if they have had any complaints I suppose.

Comment: Maybe it is the chlorine or the shampoo https://www.google.com/search?q=can+chlorine+cause+stomach+ache

Comment: @user14203 I'd be pretty surprised if it is not the mikvah. But consider also that women sometimes get nauseous when they are ovulating